# How do I use Zod's isEmail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zod, trpc.io

Not sure how `isEmail` is intended to be used?

```js
.mutation("add", {
    input: z.object({
      email: z.string().min(1).isEmail(), <----- ? this doesn't seem to work / throws an error
    }),
    async resolve({ ctx, input }) {
      let user = await prisma.subscriber.create({
        data: {
          email: input.email,
        },
      });

      return { email: input.email };
    },
  });
```

I thought isEmail would simply validate the input before getting it through the schema, but this doesn't seem to be the idea?

Comment: Please don't tag your titles.

Comment: I don't see you ever calling `parse` on zods schema

Comment: Can you give an example of how that would look like for isEmail? Do I call isEmail in the right place even? Sorry, I'm a bit confused right now with trpc, typescript & zod!

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 2):

Just to focus in on why `.isEmail` is not working, I believe the correct refinement is just [`email`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#strings). The `email` refinement will validate that the string is an email, so I don't think you need the `min(1)` check as email is a stricter validation.

```js
z.object({
  input: z.string().email(),
})
```